# Is this the right way to use AVAudioPlayer, does my code look right?

Tags: iphone

Considering the code:

```
    soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"Sound"    ofType: @"wav"];    
    fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];   
    avPlayerNextLevel = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: fileURL  error: nil];
    avPlayerNextLevel1.volume = volume ;
    [soundFilePath release];
    [fileURL release];
```

To play the sound I then do

```
    if([avPlayerNextLevel prepareToPlay]){
        [avPlayerNextLevel play];
    }
```

I do this many times within my  game. Sometimes on the simulator , the sound stops playing. And when sometimes I detect memory leaks with AvAudioPlayer.

Does everything look alright with my code ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to release the instance of AVAudioPlayer that you created.  Since the above code  sets the delegate to self, just implement the following method and release there:

```
    - (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag {
    NSLog(@"Audio finished playing.");
    [player release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Why are you `release`ing a **non**-owning reference (`soundFilePath`)?
2. You don't need to manually `prepareToPlay` if you're going to invoke `play` right after.

Quoting the documentation for `play`:

> **Discussion**
>
> Calling this method implicitly calls the prepareToPlay method if the audio player is not already prepared to play.

Personally, I do this:

```
NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:
                   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:track
                                                   ofType:nil]];
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl
                                                     error:nil];
[audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
[audioPlayer play];
```

Where `audioPlayer` is an `ivar` and `track` is an `lvar` of type `NSString*` which I obtained earlier from wherever I configure the next song to play.

Comment: You are right, I have similar code and the releaseing of soundFilePath will cause an exception to occur when [player release] executes.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on something similar but I was using a slightly different piece of code. Unfortunately, I got memory leaks, therefore I decided to give a try to the code you posted. Same result: memory leaks again when I invoke [audioPlayer play];

I can't really figure out what's going on. Are you guys aware of any memory leaks when AVAudioPlayer is involved?